# How to detect iPad 4 from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ipad, browser-detection

There are ways to detect

- iPad 1
- iPad 2
- iPad 3
- iPad Air

How to detect iPad 4 gen from JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

By using WEBGL_debug_renderer_info extension, which is part of the [WebGL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API), you are able to retrieve the vendor of the GPU and the renderer name.

Combining this with screen dimensions of the device you can accurately define which version it is.

```
 // iPad model checks.
function getiPadModel(){
    // Create a canvas element which can be used to retreive information about the GPU.
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    if (canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        if (context) {
            var info = context.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_renderer_info");
            if (info) {
                var renderer = context.getParameter(info.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);
            }
        }
    }    

if(window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1024 / 768) {
    // iPad, iPad 2, iPad Mini
    if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1) {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPad, iPad 2, iPad Mini";
            case "PowerVR SGX 535":
                return "iPad"
            case "PowerVR SGX 543":
                return "iPad 2 or Mini";
        }
    // iPad 3, 4, 5, Mini 2, Mini 3, Mini 4, Air, Air 2
    } else {
        switch(renderer) {
            default:
                return "iPad 3, 4, 5, Mini 2, Mini 3, Mini 4, Air, Air 2";
            case "PowerVR SGX 543":
                return "iPad 3";
            case "PowerVR SGX 554":
                return "iPad 4";
            case "Apple A7 GPU":
                return "iPad Air, Mini 2, Mini 3";
            case "Apple A8X GPU":
                return "iPad Air 2";
            case "Apple A8 GPU":
                return "iPad Mini 4";
            case "Apple A9 GPU":
                return "iPad 5, Pro 9.7";
        }
    }
// iPad Pro 10.5
} else if (window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1112 / 834) {
    return "iPad Pro 10.5";
// iPad Pro 12.9, Pro 12.9 (2nd Gen)
} else if (window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1366/ 1024) {
    switch(renderer) {
        default:
            return "iPad Pro 12.9, Pro 12.9 (2nd Gen)";
        case "Apple A10X GPU":
            return "iPad Pro 12.9 (2nd Gen)";
        case "Apple A9 GPU":
            return "iPad Pro 12.9";
    }
} else {
    return "Not an iPad";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe parsing user agent using "navigator.userAgent" javascript instruction.

see also this post: [iPad version detection in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400489/ipad-version-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't help. UserAgent contains OS version

Comment: Ops, reading that post seems that you could identify difference between iPad 1 and newest using event.acceleration, and 
window.devicePixelRatio to distinguish iPad 2 and iPad 3. So user agent is not as reliable as i thought...