# Target iPad3 but not iPad4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, ipad-3

I'm try to add some css that will need to execute on iPad 3, but not iPad 4 or vice verse. I'm able to target both leaving the old version with:

```
   @media
   only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
   only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
   only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
   only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { }
```

but so far I can't find a difference to target between 3 and 4. Any css or JS solutions out there. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Impossible using CSS/Media queries I'm afraid, since they have the same screen and resolution.  Might be possible using Javascript and some UA sniffing, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400489/ipad-version-detection-in-javascript  (This post is older than the iPad 4 but maybe it can be detected in the same way.)

Why do you need to distinguish between iPad 3 and 4 anyway?

Comment: because the templates behavior is different on the 2 devices and the timeframe I have is not enough to recode it (though it might come to that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get any difference by using media queries or user-agents:

- Media queries are the [same](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)
- User Agent contains only `iPad` word, not version. Other info in UA is about `iOS` or `Safari` browser. `iPad3` has iOS6 be default, but in can be updated for new versions. `Safari` depends from `iOS` version, so system and browser information is imprecise.

So there is only `javascript`+`iOS` feature detecting like was with `iPad` and `iPad2` difference in `event.acceleration`, but there is no different in features of `iPad3` and `iPad4`.

So you can't detect `iPad3` only. May be you post here the problem with `iPad3` and we can help you to solve it?

**BUT:**

If you use `WebView` component, you can do it in it. You can detect in by `systemInfo.machine` string in `Objective-C:`

```
NSString *machineName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`machineName` for iPad3 are `iPad3,1`, `iPad3,2` and `iPad3,3`. `iPad4` are `iPad3,4`, `iPad3,5` and `iPad3,6` (don't ask why:)

And in `WebView` you can change your css file to `iPad3.css` by using `WebResourceLoadDelegate` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that you can't get any difference by media queries or user-agents, I've found a difference between *iPad3* and *iPad4* using **WebGL** and **js**.

Using [EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic/) and its extension object MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT you can return the maximum available anisotropy for a texture.

IPad3 returns **2**, iPad4 returns **16**

I guess this is due to their different GPU.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/michele7/pen/YPadbm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Anisotropy</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p style="font-size: 100px;" id="anisotropy_val"></p>   

     <canvas id="webGLCanvas" width="400" height="400">
     </canvas>

</body>
<script>

function check_max_anisotropy() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("webGLCanvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");


var ext = (
  gl.getExtension('EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic') ||
  gl.getExtension('MOZ_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic') ||
  gl.getExtension('WEBKIT_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic')
);

if (ext){
  var max = gl.getParameter(ext.MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);
}

document.getElementById("anisotropy_val").innerHTML = max;

}

check_max_anisotropy();

</script>
</html>
```